# Setting movieClip width and height fails

Tags: actionscript-3

Odd problem here – hopefully I am making a really stupid mistake.

In an AIR project, I am loading a local .swf in a custom class (a subclass of MovieClip) using an instance of `SWFLoader`. When the `Event.COMPLETE` event occurs, the method below gets called. Nothing special is going on.

The problem is that when I set the width and height of my custom class in that method, sometimes it "takes" and sometimes it doesn't. Here is the Console output for loading a few of these on the fly. I am using dummy values (100). The swfs loaded are exactly the same and each is loaded successfully but one instance of my custom class reflects the dimensions set but the other one doesn't.

```
     swf 20 50
     this: instance1120
     width: 100 height: 100
     x: 100 y: 100
     rotation: 0


     swf 20 50
     this: instance1122
     width: 0 height: 250
     x: 100 y: 100
     rotation: 0
```

---

```
protected function btn_completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            eventBtn.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, btn_completeHandler);

            if(_source.type == "swf"){
                swf = eventBtn.content as MovieClip;

                trace("swf", swf.width, swf.height);

                this.removeChildren();
                this.addChild(swf);

                swf.x = -swf.width/2;
                swf.y = -swf.height/2;

                this.x = 100;
                this.y = 100;
                this.width = 100;
                this.height = 100;
                this.rotation = 0;

                trace("this:", this.name);
                trace("width:", this.width, "height:", this.height);
                trace("x:", this.x, "y:", this.y);
                trace("rotation:", this.rotation);

                trace("\n");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you :
[Set width/height of a movieclip in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164016/set-width-height-of-a-movieclip-in-as3)

You should make sure the swf child was properly added before changing its parent's width.

I would try something like this  :

```
    protected function btn_completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        eventBtn.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, btn_completeHandler);

        if(_source.type == "swf"){
            swf = eventBtn.content as MovieClip;

            trace("swf", swf.width, swf.height);

            this.removeChildren();
            swf.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
            this.addChild(swf);

            swf.x = -swf.width/2;
            swf.y = -swf.height/2;
        }
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        this.x = 100;
        this.y = 100;
        this.width = 100;
        this.height = 100;
        this.rotation = 0;

        trace("this:", this.name);
        trace("width:", this.width, "height:", this.height);
        trace("x:", this.x, "y:", this.y);
        trace("rotation:", this.rotation);

        trace("\n");
    }
```